# How can perform facet aggregation in ReactiveMongo with playframework?

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I am trying to run `$facet` aggregation in order to get documents  according to `$match` with `$skip` and the count of matching documents.

I found there is no `$facet` aggregation in ReactiveMongo. How can I do this in my playframework 2.7 app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any aggregation stage can be written using [`PipelineOperator`](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/api/reactivemongo/api/commands/AggregationFramework.html#PipelineOperator) (if no convenient function provided).